# python module not found error no module named

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I have a few seperate pythone file and I am using them to import another py file. Modules that trying to import them are in seperate folder I code sample is below

```
from tez.library.image_crop import ImageCrop
from tez.library.image_process import ImageProcess
from tez.library.image_features import ImageFeatures
from tez.const.application_const import ApplicationConst
from tez.library.file_operation import FileOperation
```

this code is in where I want to start the py file using commond line as "python samples1.py" and thrown an error as below

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "samples1.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from tez.library.image_crop import ImageCrop ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tez'

folder structure :

> .tez 
>   -- library 
>   ---- image_crop.py 
>   ---- image_process.py 
>   ---- image_features.py 
>   --src
>   ---- samples1.py

Python version : 3.8 
Pip : 20.0.2 
Windows 10 Pro 1909

Comment: Did you install the ``tez`` package, or add it to ``PYTHONPATH``?

Comment: tez is folder name. not a package. I added folder structure in q.

Comment: By trying to import ``from tez...`` you are telling Python that ``tez`` is a package.

Comment: hm.ok then how to import python file from different folder ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a package called tez (and since you tried to import it I think you are). Then everything with tez needs to refer to itself locally. All the files in the tez package need to refer to each other with the "." and ".." imports.

In samples1.py:

```
from ..library.image_crop import <something>
```

EDIT:

It sounds like you are misunderstanding how python imports things. When you run "import X" in a python script, then python looks for a package named X under sys.path. You can append to sys.path at the top of your script if you have a custom package to look for.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<directory of tez>)

import tez
```

However, it is strongly recommended that you should not be importing from a file that is under the directory structure of the package name. If "examples" is a directory of examples that use the package "tez" then "examples" should be located outside the package "tez". If "examples" is inside the package "tez", then "examples" should be doing local imports "with-in" the package.

Getting a handle on package use can be tricky.

Comment: no tez is the folder name that some python file inside it. and another folder called src is the main folder that has my app py file want to run using command prompt

Comment: Then why do you have a line "import tez...."? This line means that tez is a package and the python kernel is going to go to that package and look for a __init__ file if it can find one.

Answer (score 1):

`sample.py` can't see above of `src` folder, but you can tell Python to do this.:

```py
import sys
import os
tez = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# __file__ is path of our file (samples.py)
# dirname of __file__ is "src" in our state
# dirname of "src" is "tez" in our state

sys.path.append(tez) # append tez to sys.path, python will look at here when you try import something

import library.image_crop # dont write "tez"
```

But this is not a very good design I think.